# Testing methods of class when instantiation creates HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

I have some tests for an object that look like as follows:

```
let(:bot) { MyObject.new('/some/config/file.json') }
```

The problem is, the very act of instantiating MyObject creates an HTTP request. The following methods that I actually want to test do not create HTTP requests at all. E.g:

```
it "should parse Jira ticket key answers correctly" do                                                  
  expect(bot.offline_method(good_answer) == correct_outcome).to eq(true)
  expect(bot.offline_method(bad_answer) == correct_outcome).to eq(false)
end
```

How can I stub out the instantiation of MyObject.new itself?

For additional context, the MyObject.new instantiates a session using the google drive gem.

If I open an interactive Ruby environment and instantiate the bot as follows, it tells me the output is thus:

```
bot = MyObject.new('/some/config/file.json')
=> #<Object:0x007f6d07a10b50 @session=#<GoogleDrive::Session:0xabcdef1234567>, @MyObject_spreadsheet_responses_1=#<GoogleDrive::Worksheet spreadsheet_id="123456789abcdefghjijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", gid="123456789", title="title of first google sheet">, @MyObject_spreadsheet_responses_2=#<GoogleDrive::Worksheet spreadsheet_id="123456789abcdefghjijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", gid="1687481303", title="second_spreadsheet_title">>
```

So how exactly do I stub

```
let(:bot) { MyObject.new('/some/config/file.json') }
```

??

I know I want something like:

```
allow_any_instance_of(MyObject.new).to return {
#<Object:0x007f6d07a10b50 @session=#<GoogleDrive::Session:0xabcdef1234567>, @MyObject_spreadsheet_responses_1=#<GoogleDrive::Worksheet spreadsheet_id="123456789abcdefghjijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", gid="123456789", title="title of first google sheet">, @MyObject_spreadsheet_responses_2=#<GoogleDrive::Worksheet spreadsheet_id="123456789abcdefghjijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", gid="1687481303", title="second_spreadsheet_title">>
}
```

But I really have no clue what the exact syntax is I want or how to find it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What library do you use to make the request? Please share the code that actually makes the HTTP request and the method that you want to test.

Comment: https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby

Would stubbing out the MyObject.new method to return nil be sufficient since the internal methods of MyObject don't actually have anything to do with the google sheet? What would this look like?

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you 3 different ways to do this:

1. Stub out the HTTP request. This can either be done using a gem like [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) (which works more 'behind the scenes') or by stubbing the google drive method (e.g. in pseudocode `allow(GoogleDrive).to receive(:some_method).and_return "fake response"`). This is the way I would recommend since it stubs out the *least* amount of code. It only stubs what's really necessary. For example, imagine you had some *other* code in your `initialize` method that you *didn't* want to stub out.
2. Stub out `initialize`. To respond to your question:

   > Would stubbing out the MyObject.new method to return nil be sufficient since the internal methods of MyObject don't actually have anything to do with the google sheet?

   Stubbing out `MyObject.new` to return nil would break your code. `.new` is expected to return an instance. It's *`initialize`* which sets up the initial state for that instance. `initialize` works by side effects only. So if you stub it out, it would be the same as having no `initialize` method at all:

   ```
   MyObject.any_instance.stub(:initialize)
   ```
3. Instead of testing `MyObject` directly, create a new class that inherits from it and overrides the `initialize` definition:

   ```
   class MyObjectDouble < MyObject
     def initialize; end
   end
   ```

   Now if you call `MyObjectDouble.new`, it will run an *empty* `initialize` block, but still have the rest of `MyObject` methods available.

   Note that you can do this without defining another constant, if you use an *anonymous class*:

   ```
   @MyObjectDouble = Class.new(MyObject) do
     def initialize; end
   end
   # => <Class:0x00007fb5842b6b28>

   @MyObjectDouble.new.class
   # => <Class:0x00007fb5842b6b28>
   ```

Comment: Thank you. So to clarify, could you provide where I can find exmaples of what I need? I'm not particularly familiar with this at all. E.g. for 2), Do I literally just write at the top of my code:

```
MyObject.any_instance.stub(:initialize).to return nil
```
?

Comment: If I had to break it down in simpler terms: do not stub `initialize` or `new`. Figure out which line inside `initialize` is triggering the HTTP request. Stub this to return some canned result. You need to do this stub _before you instantiate `MyObject`_.  It could be in the `let` block or in a `before(:each)` block.

Comment: Given what we know, I think the second part of option 1 is the way to go. That is, mock the call to GoogleDrive.auth (or whatever the method is) to return true or a canned token, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is, the very act of instantiating MyObject creates an HTTP request. The following methods that I actually want to test do not create HTTP requests

If this is true, you shouldn't be making a HTTP call in `initialize` method of the class. Just make this call in another method of the object and test it accordingly.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @attr = attr
    @external = HTTParty #It could be any gem...
  end
end
```

.
.
.

```
class MyClass
  def initialize
    @attr = attr
  end

  def call
    @external = HTTParty #It could be any gem...
  end
end
```

Comment: Good point. And my 2¢, if google drive is used extensively by `MyObject`, it can be a dependency inject, so you can pass a mock when testing.